Announcing the new Staging Ground Reviewer Stats Widget
Update on September 18th, 2024 : this feature is now live!

As a response to feedback since the launch of Staging Ground, we are excited to announce a new feature, the stats widget, launching next week. This feature is aimed at recognizing and incentivizing the invaluable contributions of our Staging Ground reviewers. Reviewers who volunteer their time and effort to help new askers improve their questions before they are posted publicly can now get a glimpse into the impact of their contributions. This initiative is part of our ongoing efforts to enhance the reviewer experience and encourage more participation in Staging Ground.

Once a reviewer has accumulated enough activity, their stats will be prominently displayed in the right sidebar on the Staging Ground homepage. This feature is currently exclusive to reviewers who participate in Staging Ground, but we are exploring the possibility of displaying relevant stats to askers in the future as well.
Reviewer stats are updated daily, with some metrics relying on activity from the last 30 days. As reviewers continue to participate in Staging Ground, their metrics will be updated regularly, allowing them to track their impact over time. Check back often to see how your contributions are making a difference!
For applicable stats, reviewers will see a colored arrow beside each metric.


Green arrows represent an increase in the stat compared to the last
30 days.
Gray arrows represent a decrease in the stat compared to the
last 30 days.
Dark brown arrows represent a neutral (neither positive    nor
negative) change in the stat compared to the last 30 days.

What are we tracking
Currently, there are six available stats. Stats are displayed based on your recent and current activity levels. They will be available once you have some activity which includes reviewing posts and applying review actions. Once you have enough activity, your stats will be displayed in the right sidebar on the Staging Ground homepage:

Reviews completed today measures the number of Staging Ground questions you reviewed today out of the daily maximum of 50.
Reviewer activity rank measures your Staging Ground activity rank out of the top 50 reviewers. Your rank is refreshed daily using your activity from the last 30 days. Activity is defined as applying eligible reviewer actions, including “edit post,” “approve and post on main site,” “conditionally approve with minor edits,” “require major changes,” “vote as off-topic,” “vote as duplicate,” and “decline request for re-evaluation.” If your rank is not in the top 50, this stat will not be visible to you.
Total askers helped measures the total number of new askers you have helped with your reviews in Staging Ground out of the total number of askers helped by all reviewers.
Total approved questions measures the total number of Staging Ground questions you approved out of the total number of questions approved by all reviewers.
Question survival rate measures the percentage of Staging Ground questions you approved that were not closed nor deleted within their first 7 days of appearing on the main site during the last 30 days.
Question success rate measures the percentage of Staging Ground questions you approved that were not closed or deleted on the main site, and received an answer or a question score of +2, during the last 30 days.

We hope this improvement will help Staging Ground reviewers see the significant impact their hard work is making. If you have suggestions on additional stats to include, we would love to hear how this widget can be improved. Please let us know below or by completing this survey, we look forward to hearing your feedback.

so... because i have no recent activity, i can't see stats on any of my past activity?

Why is this so heavily gamified? I don't need to see three different rankings for a single kind of review.

That said, I think this is a good start. Gamification without handing out internet points might be enough to up the involvement and hopefully drive more content to SG for vetting.

"Question success rate measures the percentage of Staging Ground questions you approved that were not closed or deleted on the main site, and received an answer or a question score of +2, during the last 30 days." - that is actually a fantastic signal, I'm glad this is explicitly named and catered for.

Seems to be a nice thing, but I can't see it because my activity is too low. Is calculating such stats really that resources intensive?

@NoDataDumpNoContribution I think that feature isn't live yet. Aside from that, I think it being resource-intensive isn't much of a problem but there would just not be enough data to present useful stats for users with low activity.

Seems like this leans heavily into feelgood metrics and puts the most interesting things last. I would like this more if it was only the "reviews completed", "question survival rate" and "question success rate" stats, as the other metrics look like they might send the wrong signals ("total approved" with a green arrow for a higher number implies more approvals = more better so robo-approving everything would be good according to that stat; "askers helped" is just nonsense in multiple ways, starting with the fact that you cannot know if an asker was indeed helpedby a review).

Given i only receive 3 different stats, the widget takes up less vertical space than the site bulletin and then leaves an entirely empty column for the rest of the page. Can't we put this behind a toggle-able button or something so we can get it out of the way without a browser extension?

Alternatively, it could be displayed in the unused space on the right if the screen size permits that. Even for users seeing more stats, it taking up so much horizontal space from the question list is a bit annoying.

@tanj92, OK, Thanks for the Reply. (funny to see 3 Staff-Members reply to Comments 6 days after the Announcement and just after it has gone Live, (and nothing before. but some of our "concerns" have influenced the "final result" => Compliment...!) but anyway), maybe worth putting all your Replies (from all 3 Staff-Members) in some "FAQ" Answer, it's difficult to read them one by one, and Comments are never sure to last long(er)/for ever...

ETA btw when Reviewers will get some Rep for the time and energy they spend doing curation and quality-control in the 'SG'...?

Reminder to please post anything that you want staff to respond to as an answer.  Back-and-forth discussions in comments are very hard to follow due to the lack of threading.  Don't worry too much about whether it's a proper answer for feedback posts like this.  I've extracted everything that staff members responded to into answers, though there are other things that could/should ideally be answers.

@dan1st, about your "it could be displayed" + "it taking up so much horizontal space", no idea what "it" is, some previous Comment of yours got probably taken into some Staff-Answer, and deleted, => a bit unclear now what "it" might mean... => Maybe worth to completely re-post your Comment as a standalone one...

@chivracq This is a response to Kevin B's comment where I suggested an alternative to a toggle-able button.

This doesn't make me feel incentivized.

@dan1st Ah, OK, makes sense... (The "Alternatively" felt like your Comment was a continuation on some previous Comment (from you also) that could have been removed or moved to one of the standalone Answers, but now I understand...)

Should the post also provide an actual link to https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground where you may or may not find this statistic? This is somewhat unobvious; I had to hunt it down by visiting an SG question from the front page, and then clicking through from there.

@tripleee I mean, the first image shows the Staging Ground landing page so it should be ok in my opinion.

A screen shot of somebody else's stats is less ... engaging than being able to explore your own.

I meant that the screenshot shows where you can find the stats.

Please make this feature available to all reviewers, even those who haven't yet "accumulated enough activity." That'll make it much easier to notice when your reviewed posts are doing badly, which helps you become a better reviewer!
To put it differently - if someone's reviewed posts have a 1% survival rate, isn't that something they should know now rather than later?

"Please don't gatekeep this feature to users who have "accumulated enough activity."" Well, this viewpoint tracks with the change they made recently to reputation leagues. They only track the top 500 users or something like that. It would undercut their argument about tracking all users being too expensive if they suddenly tracked all users' performance for a new activity league.

@TylerH That's fair. I suppose I'd also add on "please treat this as an informational stats page, not a competitive league."

We will reconsider displaying all stats regardless of reviewer activity level—except, of course, for reviewers with 0 reviews, who would receive an empty state version of stats instead.

bug status-review
I just got access to the stats widget today, but even though I have approved questions that fit the survival criteria, my survival rate currently shows as 0% (which puts me in the top 1% of reviewers! ). I assume this data hasn't been filled in yet?


Well I have some data in it, but I'm at 1% survival rate… of four questions approved, I'd expect that only 0%, 25%, 50%, 75% and 100% would be possible values for me. It seems to me they somhow don't correctly filter the total number of questions approved and thus divide by a number that is much too large.

Thanks for the report, I'm looking into this now.

I also see 1% out of 10 posts that I have approved. Something is off.

This is definitely broken, and it might take a few days to get it fixed. I am first improving our prod debugging for this widget so I can be sure that my changes are truly fixing the issue. I'm swimming in an endless sea of SQL queries... I appreciate your patience during this trying time :). I'll keep you updated!

All good! Figured something wasn't right :)

"Survival"...!? I thought 'Survival' and 'Success' Rates didn't make it to the Implementation, (which I found/find a pity, the more data/indicators, the better, all Reviewers are "analytic"..., and those 2 were the best Indicators...), I only have 2 Indicators: "Total Askers Helped" + "Total Approved Qt's"...

@chivracq The survivial and success rates are behind a "Show more" button if you have approved sufficiently many questions.

@dan1st Thanks for your Reply, first.. Ah...!, if-if-if, well, apparently I don't qualify for if-if-if, as I don't see any 'Show more' Button/Link, (I only do a Review from time to time now, waiting for Rep to be rewarded to Reviewers like was announced in some other Thread), I would like a 'Show More' B/L with many more Stats/Indicators: 'SG' Stats comparing to all/'Wizard' Qt's, for myself and all 'SG' Qt's, and for 'SG' Qt's, how many entered 'SG', got Approved/'Minor Changes', staid in 'Major Changes' / 'Re-Evaluate', ended 'Off-Topic' + 'Dupe, got automatically posted after 24h, etc..

[... cont] +'Survival' & 'Success' for my 'SG' Qt's All-times/30days, all 'SG' Qt's, all Qt's/Wizard Qt's.

I guess the survival/sucess rates don't make sense for users who only reviewed a few questions. In the extreme case of only a single review, this would either be 0 or 100% and might jump to 50% on the next review.

If you want information about the total questions (in a specific state), you can use the filters but these don't check for automatic publishing (You can also use them in combination with the "Your reviewed posts" filter). You might want to activate the "Show Inactive posts", "Show skipped posts" and "Show archived posts">"Deleted" (not the other filters for archived posts) filters to see all questions.

Reporting back in, looks like there's data for survival rate now, but not success rate just yet.

Yep - just came here to update. Survival rate is fixed and now it's on my plate for this week to fix success rate as well! Same problem, I'll post more details about the fix once I have them both in. Thanks for your patience!

Looks like there's data for success rate now, too!

For many metrics, only the reviewer that "Approve and publish"es a post gets credit for it

It seems like only the reviewer that "Approve and publish"es a post gets credit for it (for metrics 4,5,6), even if someone else actually spent their time in the back-and-forth with OP. Wouldn't we want to incentivize the time-consuming edit-feedback-repeat process rather than making the stats based around approvals? – ipodtouch0218 [15 upvotes]

Staff response:

@ipodtouch0218 We apologize for not considering this as part of the first iteration of the widget. We acknowledge that this is not a perfect representation of all of the reviewers' contributions because multiple reviewers can provide feedback in a post which should be reflected in some way in the widget. We will take this into account for the next iteration of the widget to represent the effort put into a review even if the person was not the one to approve the post. – Bella_Blue [2 upvotes]

This post was extracted from the comments for ease of following discussions.

Yep, completely agree with @ipod, most "work" is being done in back and forth "Major Edit", when the Asker reacts of course, can  take 8-10hours, we go to sleep at some point, 'SO' is for the whole world, with different time-ranges, then Qt is OK, and "somebody else" will approve the Qt, getting "all the credit" for "the back and forth work upfront"...

feature-request (or stat-request)

If you have suggestions on additional stats to include, we would love to hear how this widget can be improved. Please let us know below or by completing this survey

Let me get an idea out here.
I have the opinion that providing good reviews/improving questions should be incentivized over robo-reviewing/providing any reviews.
With that in mind, I think it would be good to have a statistics about questions that actually improved.
My concrete suggestion is to include the number of questions where the reviewer used the "Requres Major Changes" or "Conditionally approve pending minor edit" option followed by the asker editing their question which then goes on to be approved.
I could also imagine including reviewer edits where the question is later approved (by the same or other reviewers).
I would suggest the name "Questions improved" or similar for that.

What is the definition of "helping" an asker?

What is your definition of "helping" an asker? – dan1st [2 upvotes]

Staff response:

@dan1st Any reviewers who have applied eligible review actions (eg, major changes, minor edits, approved, edited post). Comments added were not included as part of the criteria to simplify the query. We can reconsider adding comments for the use case where a reviewer added a comment but did not take action because another reviewer had already done so. – Bella_Blue

This post was extracted from the comments for ease of following discussions.

status-completed
At the bottom of the new help page for the stats there is a sentence suggesting to complete a survey:

Please complete this survey to provide feedback.

But no survey is actually linked anywhere on that page. I believe this is supposed to point to the survey linked in the question here.

Fixed, thanks for the catch!

What is "enough activity" to see these stats?

Yeah, could you define "enough activity"...?, what is the metric/threshold...?, all times/last 30 days...? // I don't understand the "vs" in "vs last 30 days" for a few sections, compared to "in last 30 days" for other sections...? // In 'Reviewer activity rank', "edit post" (all commas should be outside the double quotes btw) is mentioned, while it doesn't count as a Review. – chivracq [5 upvotes]

Staff response:

@chivracq We classify reviewers based on their last 30 days of activity as either "low" or "high" activity. A reviewer rank is applied (i.e. 1, 2, 3, etc). The top 150 reviewers are classified as "high activity" and anyone ranked lower than this would be considered low activity. The all time metric (the denominator value) in “total askers helped” and “total approved questions” accounts for all reviewers, only the numerator reflects your direct contributions. In the example screenshot, 2.3k helped out of 29k means you helped 2.3k askers out of 29k askers helped by all reviewers. – tanj92

This post was extracted from the comments for ease of following discussions.

I'm not too fond of Rankings, but hum, if you want more participation, not an idea to display that Ranking...? If I'm a somewhat regular Reviewer at #136 and I see I'm coming down, close to 150 and might "disappear" from the Ranking,, that might motivate me to remain in the Top-150, same with sbd at #167 who will get motivated to come into the Top-150...

feature-request
Currently, the "Question survival rate" and "Question success rate" stats are hidden behind a "Show more" button:

Would it be too much trouble to show them by default?

Why was gray chosen to represent a decrease, rather than red?

Is there any reason that the gray color is picked to represent a decrease, instead of the usual choice of red? – ray [1 upvote]


I would assume because red suggests "negative" as well, @ray , however, there can be many reasons people's activity can go down (in the SG): other commitments, holidays, boredom, no questions sent to the SG, etc, etc. Red could imply you're doing a "bad job" and I kinda am on sind that I don't want to see I'm "performing badly" because no questions in the tags I follow went to the SG that day/week. – Thom A [4 upvotes]


@ThomA This is kind of subjective, but it looks like a sensible interpretation to me. Actually, I have no opinion on whichever colour is picked. I just want to understand the reason behind the choice. – ray


I also wouldn't be surprised if the colour choice is due to "accessibility" reasons, @ray . Stack Overflow are on a big hype at the moment of making things "more accessible" by making the UX different/odd/worse. – Thom A

Staff response:

@ray like other users theorized we didn't want the user experience to be too negative so chose gray to be more neutral instead of the red. – Bella_Blue [3 upvotes]

This post was extracted from the comments for ease of following discussions.

Not enough content is going to SG right now

Great, and I'll never appear on it because you refuse to send content to the SG... Fix the SG first then add game features... – Thom A [8 upvotes]


Since I only review the stuff that's in my wheelhouse it's gonna be a while before I get the stats, methinks. I've yet to see 50 C++ SG questions in one day, and trust me you don't want me <expletive deleted>ing around in the python questions. – user4581301

Staff response:

@ThomA Our ideal state is for all new askers' questions to go through Staging Ground first, until they have successfully graduated. But that requires having enough reviewers to handle the load (something we are actively working towards). If we opened the floodgates tomorrow, a significant number of these questions would end up auto-graduated after 24 hours, before reviewers have a chance to tackle them. We are slowly but surely increasing the number of posts that are routed to Staging Ground, as long as we have enough reviewers to handle them. – Sasha

Further discussion, part 1:

@Sasha "a significant number of these questions would end up auto-graduated after 24 hours": Yeah, and...? The worst case is that those Askers will have to wait for 24h before their Qt gets posted on the 'Main'-Site. I'm pretty sure the worst ones will be intercepted... That's already a win-win.. – chivracq [1 upvote]


@chivracq If there aren't sufficiently many reviewers, it may not result in the worst questions not being intercepted but just a small kind of random sample being intercepted. Also, some potentially good questions being stuck in Re-Evaluate forever because no one looks at them in the Staging Ground and these can't auto-graduate. – dan1st [1 upvote]


@dan1st. For the "Stats", I'm pretty sure some Reviewers will love to do the 'Re-Evaluate' Qt's, and approve everything that is fairly OK... Maybe not best, but the overall quality will still go up... (I currently see quite many Qt's staying in 'Major Changes' or 'Re-Evaluate' while the quality is already pretty decent, for a non-SME in the main Tag...) – chivracq


@chivracq that assumes these reviewers even seeing those questions which I'm not sure about if all questions would go to the SG. – dan1st

Further discussion, part 2:

"Our ideal state is for all new askers' questions to go through Staging Ground first, until they have successfully graduated" And that's fine, but at the moment you're sending about 2% (finger in the air, randomly generated number) of users that should go to the SG to the SG; the rest skip it completely; that's significantly worse that asking 98% of those users to "wait" 24 hours. So what if, at the moment, they get released after 24 hours? That's better that sending 95% of bad material straight to the website because Stack Overflow won't commit to onboarding... – Thom A


@ThomA If you consider it worse, that may not be the case for others. While I am not sure which option would be better or worse, I can understand not wanting to add an unnecessary delay to almost all questions, especially if the current system seems to work (e.g. in the perspective of the company) and a useless delay can do active damage (as opposed to just keeping the current state which wouldn't make it actively worse). – dan1st [1 upvote]


"I can understand not wanting to add an unnecessary delay to almost all questions" But that is actually Stack Overflow's goal, @dan1st , to send all eligible questions to the SG and remain there until they are released (no auto release after 24 hours). So some will sit there until reviewed, which might be quite quick, and others could remain in "purgatory" for days (or weeks), like edit suggestions. – Thom A


Yes but the goal is for these questions to be handled, not for them to remain in the Staging Ground without anyone looking at it. – dan1st [1 upvote]


And sending everything to the SG allows for that, @dan1st . Sending barely anything to it does not. – Thom A


It allows them going into the Staging Ground without anyone looking at these questions. – dan1st

This post was extracted from the comments for ease of following discussions.

"you're sending about 2%", @Thom I think, yep-yep, hence my Sugg (in some other Thread) to rate all incoming Qt's with [1-5] for "Quality", and [1-3] go automatically to 'SG', configurable, 'SG'=100% Q1=50% Q2=30% Q3=20%, just an idea, configurable again... :idea:

@chivracq How are they rated for quality?

@Syed, => Based on some heuristics giving a global quality score, for ex: Post length, Code Block(s)/Snippet(s) present, Formatting used, spell and grammar checks, capitalization used at the beginning of sentences, "i"<>"I", number of punctuation signs (per Post length, excluding Code Blocks, of course), if Image Link included => check through OCR if doesn't contain Code or Error Msg, presence of "noise" (Thanks/Thank you (in advance)/TIA/help/appreciated/etc...). Could also run a search using the Title + Tag(s), the number of results will mean something for large Tags...
